# Empty variable after using cmd.exe set from makefile target on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, makefile

Using the following Makefile..

```makefile
.PHONY: default
default:
  @set TEST=test
  @echo TEST is %TEST%
```

.. and then running `make` outputs.. `TEST is`

Running the same in cmd results in.. `TEST is test`

I have also tried doing both on one line, which didn't work either. Running `make` using the following Makefile..

```makefile
.PHONY: default
default:
  @set TEST=test & echo TEST is %TEST%
```

.. outputs.. `test is`

The same in cmd outputs.. `test is test`.

Make is installed from chocolatey.
Output of `make --version` starts with..

```
GNU Make 4.4.1
Built for Windows32
```

Comment: Read [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/) in addition to correct information posted by [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) in the answer below. It should work using `set "TEST=test" & call echo TEST is %%TEST%%` to define on same line an environment variable and reference its string value. The disadvantage is that the usage of `call` for a double parsing of the command line right to this command results in searching for a file with name `echo` in file system using the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

make always runs every command line in a separate shell.  That means variables set on one command line will be lost when that command line completes and a new one starts.

If you were using a real shell, like POSIX sh, instead of Windows cmd batch files, this would be trivial because it's very easy to combine multiple logical lines into one physical line in sh.  For example this will work:

```
.PHONY: default
default:
        TEST=test; \
        echo TEST is $$TEST
```

However combining multiple lines into one in Windows batch syntax is much harder.